# Is possible to do a custom binder on an array of input fields using RxSwift?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, rxjs, rx-swift

I have two input fields, one for password and another one to confirm the password. I want to create a custom binder that will allow me to compare the value of both input fields but also validate minimum amount of chars. I had a pretty similar question but not regarding comparing two different fields ([Is there some sort of Priority operator on RxSwift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59690848/is-there-some-sort-of-priority-operator-on-rxswift/59690956#59690956)) and based on the answer for that previous question I've been trying to do something like this:

```
enum PasswordCreateValidation {
    case valid
    case lessThanMinimum
    case confirmationLessThanMinimum
    case differentInputs
}

extension Reactive where Base: [InputField] {
    var rxPassword: Binder<PasswordCreateValidation> {
        return Binder<[InputField]>(self.base) { control, value in
            switch value {
            case .valid :
                control[0].errorLabel.isHidden = true
                control[1].errorLabel.isHidden = true
                control[0].separator.backgroundColor = .white
                control[1].separator.backgroundColor = .white
            case .lessThanMinimum:
                control[0].errorLabel.isHidden = false
                control[0].separator.backgroundColor = .red
                control[0].errorLabel.text = "Needs more chars"
            case .confirmationLessThanMinimum:
                control[1].errorLabel.isHidden = false
                control[1].separator.backgroundColor = .red
                control[1].errorLabel.text = "Needs more chars"
            case .differentInputs:
                control[0].errorLabel.isHidden = false
                control[0].separator.backgroundColor = .red
                control[0].errorLabel.text = "Inputs are not the same"
                control[1].errorLabel.isHidden = false
                control[1].separator.backgroundColor = .red
                control[1].errorLabel.text = "Inputs are not the same"
            }
        }
    }
}

...

private func bind() {
    let codeMinimum = codeInputField.textField.rx.text.orEmpty.map { $0.count >= 1 }.skip(2)
    codeMinimum.bind(to: codeInputField.rx.nonEmpty).disposed(by: bag)

    let minimumAmountPassword = 8
    pwdInputField.minimumAmountOfChars = minimumAmountPassword
    confirmPwdInputField.minimumAmountOfChars = minimumAmountPassword

    let pwdMinimum = pwdInputField.textField
        .rx.text.orEmpty.map { $0.count >= minimumAmountPassword }.skip(2)
    let confPwdMinimum = confirmPwdInputField.textField
        .rx.text.orEmpty.map { $0.count >= minimumAmountPassword }.skip(2)

    pwdMinimum.bind(to: pwdInputField.rx.minimumChars).disposed(by: bag)
    confPwdMinimum.bind(to: confirmPwdInputField.rx.minimumChars).disposed(by: bag)

    let pwdEqualA = pwdInputField.textField.rx.text.orEmpty
        .map { $0 == self.confirmPwdInputField.value }.skip(2)

    let pwdEqualB = confirmPwdInputField.textField.rx.text.orEmpty
        .map { $0 == self.pwdInputField.value }.skip(2)

    let equality = Observable.combineLatest(pwdEqualA, pwdEqualB) { $0 && $1 }
    let minimum = Observable.combineLatest(pwdMinimum, confPwdMinimum) { $0 && $1 }
    let pwdValidation = Observable.combineLatest(equality, minimum) { $0 && $1 }

    Observable.combineLatest(pwdValidation, codeMinimum) { $0 && $1 }
        .startWith(false)
        .bind(to: signInButton.rx.isActive)
        .disposed(by: bag)
}
```

Seems my custom binder is wrong. isn't it allowed to have an array as Base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’d make a view that has two input fields and use that view as the base